# why does proxy reverse included to a single virtualhost configuration via post virtualhost include affect other virtual hosts on same vps

Tags: linux, centos, apache-virtualhost

I have created a virtualhost configuration file in the specified directory `/etc/apache2/conf.d/userdata/std/2_4/username/sub.domain.com/file.conf` (in this example for `sub.domain.com`.)

I have also included this file via the include editor via post virtualhost include, but every other domain which also has separate default virtualhosts still directs to the app running on `http://127.0.0.1:5000`.

The code in the include file is below:

```
ProxyPass / http://127.0.0.1:5000/
ProxyPassReverse / http://127.0.0.1:5000/
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I did was I opened up the `post_virtualhost_global.conf` file found in `/etc/apache2/includes/`.

Then I removed the include statement from the `post_virtualhost_global.conf` file, then it worked, I don't seem to understand how, but it worked perfectly anyway. I have also applied same practice for subsequent virtualhost proxyreverse includes I have done afterward.